# Docker can't access django localhost

Tags: python, django, docker

I have Django 3.2.18 installed and it works perfectly fine. the problem starts when I want to start a django project and use docker containers. my Dockerfile content is like this:

```
FROM python:3.9.13
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./core /app

CMD ["python","manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

I run `docker build -t django .` and it builds the project fine! it also runs perfect. but the moment I enter https://0.0.0.0:8000 in my browser it fails. Insted of django debug first page (The page with a rocket), it shows me `This site can’t be reached` as if it can't access my localhost. At first I thought it was my windows build version that was the problem, but I've upgraded my windows and still no defrence!

I have searched the Internet and no one seeem to had this problem before.
Changed my OS version.
Deleted and re-created my django project.

I'm expecting to see django first page on `https://0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: How are you running the container? `docker run -p 8000 ...`, right?

Comment: yes...docker run -p 8000:8000 django

Comment: I tested the proccess on ubuntu now and it works! Idk what is wrong with the windows version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was I was browsing `https://0.0.0.0:8000` because I thought that was the case and I should check the address I have entered, but it seems I should put `https://0.0.0.0:8000` in the docker file and check `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`.